# Not able to pull or push in the github repository

Tags: git, github, gitlab, git-bash

I am new in the git world. I am not able to understand why I am not able to pull or push things in the github repository.
    This is the link for the clone
    https://github.com/Mohsin05/developer.git

I am using these commands....

```
$ git init
$ git config --global user.name "mohsin05"
$ git config --global user.email "mohsinyounas@gmail.com"
$ git clone https://github.com/Mohsin05/developer.git
$ git remote -v
$ git add .
$ git commit -am"First"
$ git push origin master
```

My folder on the computer is updated with respect to the github repository but when i make any change in the file and try to push it gives this error

> fatal: 'origin' does not appear to be a git repository
>
> fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
>
> Please make sure you have the correct access rights
>   and the repository exists...

Moreover I can not create any new branch and it does not sync.

Comment: Remove everything, don't `git init`, `cd` to the directory after cloning

Comment: @Danh Make it an answer, as you’re (probably) correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you're not creating a commit on your clone of the github repository, you're creating a commit on a repo in the parent directory of the cloned github repo. This is because your script is actually creating two git repos on your local machine: One in the initial directory (`git init`) and then one in a child directory (`git clone`)--git clone will checkout the code from github and put it in a child directory from where it's called. Based on what you're describing you don't need to do the `git init` (that's for creating a brand new repository).

What you really want is something along the lines of:

```
git clone https://github.com/Mohsin05/developer.git
cd developer
touch First
git add First
git commit -am"First"
git push origin master
```

This clones your github repo, switches (`cd`s) into the repo directory, creates a file named `First`, adds it to the repo, commits it with the comment `First`, and the pushes it up to github.